# How should I group a collection of minor tasks in Jira?

Tags: user-stories, jira

A specific function in an existing product needs a couple of minor GUI adjustments. Should I create a user story for each adjustment or a single user story whar I list all adjustments as e.g. acceptance criteria? Any other options? (currently using Jira).

Example of adjustments (affects same GUI):

- Change title of user card.
- Change user icon.
- Adjust description from X to Y.
- Change exit button color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single answer - you should ask the team to see what they prefer.

If the changes need to be delivered together as a single entity, it may be easier to have a single issue that captures all the changes. The team may opt to use subtasks to capture the different pieces and even distribute the work to different team members.

If the changes can be delivered independently, it becomes less important how they are grouped. The team may want the flexibility to plan and pull the work independently while giving visibility into how each change is ordered among the other changes. However, making several issues does add overhead related to time and tracking.